# Function not working correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to create an exponent function and it does not seem to work as expected. Sorry if I don't understand some basic things, I'm just learning bits and pieces off the internet.

```
float x;
float y;
float z;
int h;
int j;

float exponent (float a, float b)
{
    float r;
    while(b > 1)
    {
        r = a * a;
        b = b - 1;
    }
    return (r);
}
```

^Snippet of the function with variables.

```
cout << "EXPONENT MODE\n\n";
cout << "Please enter a number:  ";      
cin >> x; system("CLS");
cout << "Please enter another number as the exponent for the first:  ";
cin >> y; 
z = exponent(x, y); 
cout << "Calculating the answer, please wait";
Sleep(1000); 
cout << "."; 
Sleep(1000);
cout << "."; 
Sleep(1000); 
cout << "."; 
Sleep(1000);
cout << "\n\nYour answer is : "; 
cout << r; 
Sleep(5000); 
system("CLS");
cout << "Would you like to calculate another set of numbers? (yes = 1, no = 2) :  ";
cin >> h; 
system("CLS");
```

^Part I want to execute on the console.(Just code)

Basically, I want the user to input 2 numbers, the first(x) being the base number, the second(y) being the exponent. The program should input x as a and y as b and run the function. What happened: Input 1: 5, Input 2: 3, Expected: 125, Received: 25. I'm thinking about changing the while to (b > 0). If you guys could help that would be great!.
(Also don't judge me on the `system("CLS")` in the code)

Comment: Your exponent function will only calculate squares (`a * a`).

Comment: ...repeatedly. the *same* square. and you better initialize `r` to `1.0` when entering this thing once you fix it. And of course, this makes zero effort to use the fractional exponent, so `b=1.5`, for example, will fail.

Comment: I see what I did wrong with the math. But if I input 5, 3 shouldn't the output be 25 * 25 since 5*5 = 25?

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple, you're printing the wrong variable.

```
cout << "\n\nYour answer is : "; 
cout << r;
```

`r` is a local member variable of `exponent`. In the scope of `main`, the result of `exponent` was actually stored in a variable called `z`

```
z = exponent(x, y);
```

The fix is just to change your answer printing code to

```
cout << "\n\nYour answer is : "; 
cout << z;
```

For your own benefit, you might want to try giving your variables more meaningful names and only declaring them in scopes where they are actually needed. I don't see you using `r` elsewhere in main, did you make it global in an attempt to try and make the `r` in `exponent` accessible there too?

Comment: +1 to the wrong variable being printed, though with the exception of the single case where `b==2`, printing `z` will be no more accurate, as the function itself is broken.

Comment: It seems like he's on the way to fixing the exponent function itself, just seemed to be tangled in the haystack of crazy variable names he's given himself (see edits to the answer ;)

Comment: The function is returning `r` so would `cout << z;` work? Also, these are just basic programs for which I place letters for var names. I see what I did wrong with the math part though.

Comment: Exponent is *not* returning `r`; there is a *local* variable in exponent called `r` and when you reach the end of the function you return it's value - but you are *not* returning `r`.

You *do* store the value that's returned in a variable called 'z': `z = exponent(x, y);`. That says: "Call exponent with x and y, then store the return value in z".

Batman's name is Bruce and the actor in Die Hard is called Bruce. They're not the same person. Likewise you can have more than one variable with the same name, as has happened here.

See: http://ideone.com/TTrrMR

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input. I'm a noobie to programming in general and I started with c++ first. Any suggestions for me to learn some stuff?

Comment: You seem to be making progress - if you are working with visual studio, this would be a good time to familiarize yourself with the debugger and walk thru your programs, inspect variables, use watches. C++ has many sharp edges, learning to program with it can be painful. If you are just looking to learn to program generally, consider either "Python" or possibly "JavaScript" which you can work on in the web-browser. If you have chrome: Ctrl+Shift+J and type console.log("Hello world")

Answer (score -1):

I dont under stand what @kfsone is talking about.
but in the loop r is set as a*a everytime, isn't this why you are getting the square instead of exponent ? I think what you really want to do is this:

```
 r=1
 while( ...
    r *= a;// note to accumulate result on r
    b --;
```

Comment: `z = exponent(x, y); cout << "Calculating the answer, please wait";` followed by some dot printing followed by `cout << "\n\nYour answer is : "; cout << r;`

In shorter form: `z = exponent(...);` ... `cout << r`. Fairly simple.